# How can I save document state, letter by letter, to UNDO and REDO on Scintilla?

Tags: c++, ide, text-editor, scintilla

I am creating an IDE using Scintilla in C++. I am trying to create multiple tabs, but every tab must have its own REDO and UNDO state.

This is the behavior I would like to have:

[image: undo and redo letter by letter]

This is the behavior I have now:
[image: undo and redo erase all text]

Comment: How are you implementing undo/redo? Are you using the [Scintilla APIs](https://www.scintilla.org/ScintillaDoc.html#UndoAndRedo)? Edit your question and provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

SCI_BEGINUNDOACTION
SCI_ENDUNDOACTION
Send these two messages to Scintilla to mark the beginning and end of a set of operations that you want to undo all as one operation but that you have to generate as several operations. Alternatively, you can use these to mark a set of operations that you do not want to have combined with the preceding or following operations if they are undone.